# How can i Get container UITableView in a cell of the TableView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

is any way to access the UITableView that contains current UITableViewCell in the cell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go up the view hierarchy until you find a UITableView:

```
    UIView *v = self;
    while (v && ![v isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) v = v.superview;
    // v now holds the table view, or nil if there isn't one
```

Although you should probably question why exactly the cell is needing to poke at the table view, and whether there is a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: yeap, it works, [self superview] take the same effect， another question, how can i get the view controller of the base super view?

Comment: @Ron: Simply `[self superview]` may not always work, if a future version of iOS inserts some other view into the hierarchy between the table view and the cells. You can (normally) check if a view has a controller by seeing if `nextResponder` returns a UIViewController instead of a UIView, but again ask yourself why you're doing this.

Comment: Aha， thank you,  this question is not about any project or real implementation, i just want know how to do so. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 8+:

```
UITableView *tableView = cell.superview.superview;
```