# how to get the superview of uitableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I want to get the parent view of uitableviewcell, which was created custom. And I try to use self superview to get the parent tableview ,but it is unuseful.

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization cod
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)[self superview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:self];
        NSLog(@"%d %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
...
}
```

The value that Nslog output is totally 0.

@jrturton has given the reason why self superview can not refer to its parent view. but next question is that I want to get the indexPath when the cell initial.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110522/986169

Comment: try using self.nextResponder.

Comment: I have mentioned that self.superview is unuseful. I don't know why

Comment: It is null at that point because your cell hasn't been added to a table yet. It has no superview.

Comment: @jrturton Yes, I think that this reason cause the problem. But I want get the indexPath when initial the cell. so would your have some good suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you wanted to do that, you'd do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but this would change when the cell was reused.

Comment: You could create a property to hold the cell's indexPath or if you need it during init, create a custom init method and pass it in

Comment: @williamb really really thanks to williamb, I have solved my problem now.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    // Cast Sender to UIButton
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    // Find Point in Superview
    CGPoint pointInSuperview = [button.superview convertPoint:button.center toView:self.tableView];

    // Infer Index Path
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInSuperview];

    // Fetch Item
    NSDictionary *item = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Log to Console
    NSLog(@"%@", item[@"title"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate through the view hierachry.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745602/1169310)
will help you

Comment: thanks, I try to use the way that you provide, but it also can't work. and I post my code on above

Answer (score -3):

Try to use `[cell.contentView addSubview:imgTemp];` Hope it will help you.

Comment: I do not want to add a subview on the contentview, but thank you